# The math and the physics behind POTS phone lines

Tags: dc, ac, telephone, fourier

Since high school you learn something about Fourier Analysis and you can easily grasp the idea that a given signal that is variable over a given timeframe, is composed of multiple sub-signals with different frequencies.

Lately I learned that POTS lines work, at the same time, with both AC and DC power, the DC signal is used to feed the device, the phone, and the AC signals are the "inputs" from/to the user or the ISP ( dialing, ringtone, dtmf tones ).

This is kinda of a black magic to me, at this point, I really can't grasp how the so called multiplexing of the signal is happening.

It's true that POTS signals typically travel over RJ plugs and separate copper cables, usually there are 4 cables, so things are much simpler in practice since the 2 AC and DC are probably always separated from each other.

In modern times a phone cable also carries a DSL signal, but I'm just going to assume that this is just an "addon" to the several AC signals that a POTS line already delivers.

Anyone can explain the math/physics principles behind the multiplexing of POTS lines or phones and ADSL lines in general ?

Comment: POTs has two wires in its basic form - these carry signals and DC - 3 wires are used to allow several phones to mute the bell on parallel phones when lifting handsets and 4 wires are used on old PBX exchanges when "earth recall" features were employed but basic pots is 2 wire. Usually there are not 4 wires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You claim to be familiar with the Fourier analyses.

Take a look at this signal:

[image: DC+AC]

Here we have a sinusoidal signal summed together with a DC signal. The AC signal has voltage of 1 V peak to peak, while the dc component is 2 V. For each point on the graph, what happened is that the value of the cosinusoidal signal was summed with the 2 V DC level.

If we do Fourier transform of the signal, we'd get a value at the frequency of 0, which represents the DC component and the value at the frequency of the AC signal itself.

[image: FFT of AC+DC]

A "pure" AC signal goes from Vpeak to -Vpeak and is centered around zero. If the signal's average value is not zero, then it has "DC bias", that is to say that it can be represented as a sum of a DC signal and an AC signal that is centered around zero.

Next, a bit about phone lines and its cabling: Traditional POTS uses only two lines, one of which is ground and the other is traditionally said to be -48 V DC. The negative voltage  then summed with the actual signal which carries the data.

ADSL "basically" works same way as fax modems and voice calls: The -48 V DC is summed together with the AC signal which carries the data. At both telephone central office and at subscriber's location filters are used to separate the voice traffic from ADSL signalling. This is possible since ADSL and telephone work in different frequency bands, so they do not overlap. You can then "simply" filter out different bands and send them to different devices.

**EDIT**:
The way right to think about this is that in reality there's no "DC" and "AC" voltage (in fact, terms DC and AC aren't really all that well defined and the conventions depend on region). Those terms are simply abstractions that are used to simplify circuit analyses.

Let's say that you have grounded line G and line with voltage A. Now imagine that it's possible to measure voltage of the A line extremely quickly and that you associate one voltage measurement with one point on time axis. You'd get something that looks like this:
[image: AC+DC stem]

Each measurement point tells you "exact" voltage at the time of the measurement. You don't get two lines because there's only one actual voltage and its the voltage that's shown.

Comment: So the DC causes the shifting of the graph to the highest part of the coordinate plane and there is no flat line for the DC ? Why there are no 2 lines ? Why DC should mimic the behaviour of the AC considering that on your first graph there is just 1 line.

Comment: @user2485710 It is clearer now?

Comment: I just realized that I had a brainfart, I forgot that this concepts are related to infinitesimal calculus and somehow I was trying to port this from an analytical point of view to some algebraic/geometric representation. I have no idea what I was thinking. Yes, now I realized that is basically an AC signal shifted by as much as the intensity of the DC signal.

Answer (score 2):

It's [linear superposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) - the AC and DC components of the signal are added together. Imagine any point on the wire, it has a voltage at every time, which is the sum of an AC (+/- 1v) and DC (+48v) component. So in that example you would expect to see a reading of between 47 and 49 volts if you could freeze time and grab your multimeter.

Comment: I don't get it, over a period of time `T` the AC traces a sinusoid while DC is a flat line, how can I distinguish between the two at the point where they intersect ? And this assume that I'm getting a clear signal with no spikes.

Comment: The DC is the **average** value . (An approximate average in less than infinite time).

Comment: @akellyirl average of what ? the AC nominal value is itself an average since the AC follows a sinusoid over a period `T`. So if you have AC at 50v you can expect the graph for the AC to be bounded between -50 and +50 forming a sinusoid. The DC is a flat line AFAIK.

Comment: @user2485710, using whatever plotting program you desire, plot \$f(t) = 1 + \cos(2\pi t)\$ and tell me if you see *one* signal or *two*.  Clearly, the time average value of this function, over a period, is \$1\$ and this is the *DC component* - a constant with respect to time.  Subtracting the DC component from this function leaves a time varying signal with *zero* time average - the *AC component*.  The fact that we can *decompose* \$f(t)\$ into two components does not mean that a plot of \$f(t)\$ will show the DC and AC *components*.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri thanks, now things are clearer, it was my fault since I had this giant brainfart about calculus.